# Monoprice Select Mini v2 reattach boden tube to feeder head

Tags: ptfe-tube, monoprice-select-mini

I have a Monoprice Select Mini v2.

The Bowden tube has detached from the filament feeder head... it was actually pushed out by the filament (175 PLA) as it fed.  It appears to have been held in place by a compression fitting inside the feeder head. I think the blue plastic collar provides the compression but I hesitate to attempt to remove it for fear of making matters worse.

Looking for advice on getting the Bowden tube and compression fitting back together without wrecking the feed

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my bowden feed system, those could be the reasons:

1. the pneumatic connector is not keeping the pressure on the pipe -> replace
2. the Teflon pipe is faded/worn -> try to cut the end of the pipe
3. the hotend/nozzle is clogged -> clean/replace
4. the pipe is excessively bent and gives a lot of resistance -> that usualy needs pipe/tube replacement.
5. the nozzle temp is to low -> increase printing temperature

In some cases I had to cut the tube above the pneumatic connector and push it down to get it out as there was no way to  pull it back from the collar.